# how to calculate K8s node's cpu rate exclude master node

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

1. Metric "node_cpu_seconds_total" has all cluster nodes cpu info, I can calculate cpu rate simply by using

   rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", cluster="$cluster"}[1m])
2. `node_cpu_seconds_total` has no label to specify master node, but I can get master node list using metric `kube_node_role`:

   kube_node_role{cluster="$cluster"}
3. I use `unless` operator to eliminate the master nodes:

   node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", cluster="$cluster"} unless ON(instance) label_replace(kube_node_role{cluster="$cluster"}, "instance", "$1:9100", "node", "(.*)")
4. Now，use function `rate`,:

   rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", cluster="$cluster"} unless ON(instance) label_replace(kube_node_role{cluster="$cluster"}, "instance", "$1:9100", "node", "(.*)") [1m])

And it gives error:

> parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors"

Is there a way to do what I'm trying? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle", cluster="$cluster"}[1m])
unless on(instance)
label_replace(kube_node_role{cluster="$cluster"}, "instance", "$1:9100", "node", "(.*)")
```

Note that the `rate()` is applied only to the first part of the query, while `unless ...` part is outside the `rate()` function.

It calculates idle cpu shares for all the nodes in k8s and then suppresses the shares for master nodes discovered via `kube_node_role`. BTW, it looks like the `kube_node_role` selector must contain an additional filter on `{role="master"}` according to https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md in order to obtain series only for master nodes.